# use local image to display in webview for windows phone 8.1

Tags: webview, windows-phone-8.1, local

I have created hybrid app in Windows phone 8.1

One of my pages uses the webview control.

It has an img element on it.

I have a small image as part of the build of my application.   The 'copy to Output Directory' is set to 'Copy always'

I have followed the instructions from this page:  [enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/windows/apps/hh781229.aspx)

None of the samples work.

If I could assign that image in my c# code then that would be another alternative to use?

I would need to know how to get the absolute path of my image in my solutions and then get the ID from the webview?

I am guessing here.

Can this be done?

ADDITIONAL:

My html on aspx page on my server

```
<img src="/Images/eyeon.png" />
```

I added the eyeon.png image to my C# solution.

Comment: You have *Image* over *WebView* or you want to show image in *WebView*. Can you show some code?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the interest. I will edit my question now

Comment: If I understand correct: you have a WebView, that displays html file from server and in that html you have an Image which should be taken from the App.Package? I'm not sure, but try: `<img src="'ms-appx:///Images/eyeon.png" />`, check if your image has BuildAction set to Content. I'm not sure if that will work.

Comment: Hi again. Yes, I have tried that and it did not work. That was why I was considering setting it in C# via the native app :(

Comment: Can you debug and see what html file the *WebView* recieves?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your continued assistance. I am not sure how to do that?  I cannot view source of the control via the emulator..?

Comment: I have found out to debug. Quite a cool feature i will look at it now..

Comment: Hi, the HTMl shows: <img src="'ms-appx:///Images/eyeon.png" />

Comment: with thismessage:SEC7117: Network request to http://www.informedmotion.co.uk/NativeApp/'ms-appx:///Images/eyeon.png did not succeed.

Comment: I do not know if this message islinked: Your application manifest does not declare the following capabilities: internetClient privateNetworkClientServer

Comment: Yeah, debug is a nice feature ;) As it shows it tries to look for your image on your server.

Comment: I'm not sure if you will be able to mix sources of content (app and webserver). You may take a look at this two threads: [one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/8dba4472-e224-4000-a016-7ee2be9c450f/how-to-create-a-webview-accessible-locally-created-image-file?forum=winappswithcsharp) and [two](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/08b9b639-aaa8-41c9-bddf-204098c485ac/webview-does-not-load-msappxweb-contents-onto-https-page?forum=winappswithcsharp), maybe they will help little.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. Worth exploring :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone following this, this worked for me:

```
src = "ms-appx-web:///Images/NoFeed.jpg"
```