# Display resource map image in UWP WebView Control

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, uwp, win-universal-app

In this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh973055.aspx)

It shows us how to share out HTML with content of both text and an image through use of ResourceMap.

But the corresponding [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh973053.aspx) is not showing us how to read it and put it in the webview properly.

I know how to get the resource map back, but I don't know how best to put it into the `WebView`.

```
this.sharedResourceMap = await this.shareOperation.Data.GetResourceMapAsync();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, RandomAccessStreamReference> item in this.sharedResourceMap)
{
    ResourceMapValue.Text += "\nKey: " + item.Key;
}
```

`Item.Key` will be something like `ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41401047/display-local-images-in-uwp-webview-control/41423396#41423396 is a related question but they have the files in the local folder, where mine is in this "Assets" folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should leverage the class `IUriToStreamResolver`.

In the following example, I load the HTML file (example.html) located in `Assets` folder. The `Assets` folder also contains all images of the HTML file.
The `GetContent` method of `IUriToStreamResolver` should be overriden to transform any request to an URI specified in the HTML file (such as ) into a local uri path. In your case, you may have to tweak the `GetContent` so as to retrieves file stored by your resource map.

```
public sealed partial class WebViewLocalImage : Page
{
    public WebViewLocalImage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var uri = this.myWebView.BuildLocalStreamUri("InternalAssets", "example.html");
        this.myWebView.NavigateToLocalStreamUri(uri, new StreamUriResolver());
    }
}

public sealed class StreamUriResolver : IUriToStreamResolver
{
    public IAsyncOperation<IInputStream> UriToStreamAsync(Uri uri)
    {
        string path = uri.AbsolutePath;
        return GetContent(path).AsAsyncOperation();
    }

    private async Task<IInputStream> GetContent(string URIPath)
    {
        try
        {
            Uri localUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/" + URIPath);
            StorageFile f = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(localUri);
            IRandomAccessStream stream = await f.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            return stream.GetInputStreamAt(0);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Invalid URI");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer let me to research additional info on IUriToStreamResolver. BTW, I am writing a share target, which GetHtmlFormatAsync would return me a string from the Share Source. Since NavigateToString dont have the ability to read local image. Does that mean I have to first write the HTML fragment I received from GetHtmlFormatAsync into a file e.g. example.html, and then proceed to use BuildLocalStreamUri and NavigateToLocalStreamUri?

Comment: I have successfully read local images by using the `ms-appx-web` protocol. Try the following code:  `string htmlContent = "<br/><br/><p>Here is a local image: <img src='ms-appx-web:///Assets/Logo.png'>.</p>";
myWebView.NavigateToString(htmlContent);`

Comment: You can also store the image in the html string itself by encoding them into base64 string. Check this answer for details: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363174/use-local-images-in-webbrowser-control#34276669`. If you need to parse HTML content to modify the links, I suggest you to use HTMLAgilityPack which helped me a lot in similar functionalities.